# Where will Delphi MM4 store the logfile for memoryleaks?

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I spent a lot of time finding the file, but i cant. I only find there is such a file, refereed to as "The file", "a file", "the textfile", "the errorfile" and so on, but not the real name of the file and not where its located. Only that its in the "same folder as the application". ok. What application? My EXE? Delphi? The dfm or where?

Not an easy question to post. Som artificial intelligens tell me that my grammar is not good enough and that my question is unclear and wont let me post. It is a very clear question, but what can i do?

Comment: The default memory manager in Delphi is a _trimmed down_ version. It does not support logging leaks to a file. Get the full version at https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4

Comment: The filename of the text file is `Project1_MemoryManager_EventLog.txt` in case your project main executable file is `Project1.exe`, and it is in the very same directory as your compiled project .exe file

Comment: You have to define the option FullDebugMode to the project.

Comment: Thanx, yes I do have full mm4 installed.

Comment: When i add FullDebugMode the program will not execute...

Comment: The full debug dll must be located in the exe directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of that relates to the question you asked. You asked a simple question about where the log file was saved. Surely you have the answer.

Comment: Yes i have the answer, how do i communicate that? (mark the answer as The answer) And the answer created a new question that i cant create because som 90 min limit, thats why i tried here. I don't want to wait, i want this solved so i can get back to coding.

Comment: Yes, if David's answer solved your question as posed you should accept - [there should be a button to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) -  his answer. Doing this will also help lift some of the restrictions on [new accounts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Comment: As far as getting full debug FastMM to work, I think it's just a case of reading the instructions carefully.

Answer (score 1):

It's saved in the directory as your executable file.

Note that you have to be using the full version of FastMM4 in order to obtain a log file of leaks.